# Could I e-mail my professor and ask what my final grade will be before I graduate in two days?

Tags: professorship, grades, graduation

I am graduating in two days and still haven't received a grade in one of my classes. The chances that I do not pass the class are low but it isn't out of the question. I am also on the edge of latin honors and my grade in this class will determine where I land.

The official due date for the grades is early next week but I would really like to know if I am actually graduating before I walk. Could I e-mail the professor asking him what my grade in the class will be?

If it matters the last assignment was due a week ago.

Comment: What are Latin honours?

Comment: @astronat Magna and Summa Cum Laude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're concerned about your grade, then you can try to send a polite email. However, you may also want to check if there's a policy whereby grades for graduating seniors need to be turned in early (which may or may not be the case, given the need to make sure students can graduate.

If not, the grades might not be ready, if the submission deadline has not yet passed. (But how can they schedule graduation before grades are due?)

Also, the answer may depend on how large the class is: the bigger the course you're worried about, the less likely the grades will be ready early.